# Maximum number of blocks that can be removed from top of two stacks without exceeding the sum K

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

Given two stacks of non-negative integers. Compute the maximum number of integers that can be removed from the top of the stacks without exceeding the sum K. Suppose two stacks A and B are given as depicted in the below image. Then a maximum of 4 integers can be removed as depicted in the second image without exceeding the sum **10**. If needed please find the [source](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/game-of-two-stacks/problem) here.

[image]

[image]

I tried a DP approach to solve the problem. But I could pass only a few test cases. Can someone please tell what went wrong.

```
static int maxStacks(int maxSum, int[] a, int[] b) {
    Stack<Integer> stackA = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Integer> stackB = new Stack<>();
    for(int i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        stackA.push(a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=b.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        stackB.push(b[i]);
    }
    return solve(stackA, stackB, maxSum, 0);
}

static int solve(Stack<Integer> a, Stack<Integer> b, int maxSum, int currSum) {
    if(a.isEmpty() && b.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    int ansA;
    if(a.isEmpty()) {
        ansA = 0;
    } else {
        int peek = a.peek();
        if((currSum + peek) > maxSum) {
            ansA = 0;
        } else {
            a.pop();
            ansA = 1 + solve(a, b, maxSum, (currSum + peek));
        }
    }
    int ansB;
    if(b.isEmpty()) {
        ansB = 0;
    } else {
        int peek = b.peek();
        if((currSum + peek) > maxSum) {
            ansB = 0;
        } else {
            b.pop();
            ansB = 1 + solve(a, b, maxSum, (currSum + peek));
        }
    }
    return Math.max(ansA, ansB);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the core issue in your algorithm is coming from shallow copy of Stack. In the following code segment:

```
        } else {
            a.pop();
            ansA = 1 + solve(a, b, maxSum, (currSum + peek));
        }
```

you have already popped from stack A and so when the flow for B is executed at `ansB = 1 + solve(a, b, maxSum, (currSum + peek));`, instead of using original Stack A, you are infact passing on the modified Stack.

On a separate note, I believe this is *not* a DP solution. I would suggest you read up more on that.